# Intellij run error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gauge

i've created gauge-maven project in Intellij. i'm using 
Gauge version: 0.8.1
Gauge plugin version Version: 0.3.1
but i got error.

```
[ValidationError] /Users/muge.karakas/IdeaProjects/fghf/specs/example.spec:11 Step implementation not found => 'Vowels in English language are "aeiou".' 
[ValidationError] /Users/muge.karakas/IdeaProjects/fghf/specs/example.spec:18 Step implementation not found => 'The word "gauge" has "3" vowels.' 
[ValidationError] /Users/muge.karakas/IdeaProjects/fghf/specs/example.spec:28 Step implementation not found => 'Almost all words have vowels <table>' com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: messageType  
at com.google.protobuf.UninitializedMessageException.asInvalidProtocolBufferException(UninitializedMessageException.java:81)    
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.checkMessageInitialized(AbstractParser.java:71)   
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:168)    
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:180)    
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:185)    
at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)     at gauge.messages.Messages$Message.parseFrom(Messages.java:21442)   
at com.thoughtworks.gauge.connection.MessageDispatcher.dispatchMessages(MessageDispatcher.java:67)  
at com.thoughtworks.gauge.GaugeRuntime.main(GaugeRuntime.java:37) com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Message missing required fields: messageType   Error Message: Connection closed 
[127.0.0.1:53933] cause: EOF   Stacktrace: 
         Error Message: write tcp 127.0.0.1:53929->127.0.0.1:53933: use of closed network connection   Stacktrace:     Successfully generated html-report to => /Users/muge.karakas/IdeaProjects/fghf/reports/html-report Specifications:   0 executed  0 passed    0 failed    0 skipped Scenarios:    0 executed  0 passed    0 failed    0 skipped

    Total time taken: 118ms

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Open up (or remove) "fghf/specs/example.spec"

Comment: Could you please add your example.spec file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error not interested in spec file or any wrong installing plugin.
Did you change plugin version number from the pom.xml? It is not change automatically, you should change it manually.

Please check this link https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/563
I think u can correct this error.